# Is there a way to join a numerical column to a alphabetical column in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a table of data which contains user actions such as 'buy' and 'sell' in a column and a separate column which contains the quantity traded for the movement. Is there a way to connect the two columns that would allow me to filter results where, for example, the quantity of the brought good is greater than the quantity of the sold goods.

Example of table

| Action | Quantity | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Buy | 10 | abc |
| Sell | 9 | abc |
| short | 11 | xyz |
| cover | 11 | xyz |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only "Buy" and "Sell", or is "short" treated as "Sell" and "cover" treated as "Buy"? Are actions *really* inconsistently capitalized?

Comment: Sorry about the way I formatted it. Ideally, I would like to link 'Buy' and 'Sell' quantities together and 'Short' and 'Cover' quantities together.

Comment: You should standardize the actions. If I understand correctly there are only two actions; however, your example shows four of them.

Comment: No, there are 4 actions, 'Buy', 'Sell', 'Short' and 'Cover'.

Comment: Please show expected output, what SQL you've tried so far, and how the results of your attempt are different from expected. See See [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please correct capitalization of data values.

Comment: Depending on your use case, it might not matter. But it's generally a good practice to enumerate such a small list of possibilities. It's more compact in the database, and much better for JOINs and indexing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```sql
select product.name                     as product ,
       coalesce( bought.quantity  , 0 ) as bought  ,
       coalesce( sold.quantity    , 0 ) as sold    ,
       coalesce( short.quantity   , 0 ) as shorted ,
       coalesce( covered.quantity , 0 ) as covered
from      ( select distinct
                   t.Product as name
            from my_table t
          ) as product
left join ( select t.Quantity as quantity
            from my_table t
            where action = 'Buy'
          ) as bought on bought.product  = product.name 
left join ( select t.Quantity as quantity 
            from my_table t
            where action = 'Sell'
          ) sold on sold.product = product.name
left join ( select t.Quantity as quantity
            from my_table t
            where action = 'short'
          ) shorted on shorted.product = product.name
left join ( select t.Quantity as quantity
            from my_table t
            where action = 'cover'
          ) covered on covered.product = product.name
```

That should give you a flat result set with 1 row per product, transforming this:

| Action | Quantity | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Buy | 10 | abc |
| Sell | 9 | abc |
| short | 11 | xyz |
| cover | 11 | xyz |

Into this:

| product | bought | sold | shorted | covered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 10 | 9 | 0 | 0 |
| xyz | 0 | 0 | 11 | 11 |

Once you have flattened your table, you can filter it however you like with a simple where clause, for instance:

```sql
select product.name                     as product ,
       coalesce( bought.quantity  , 0 ) as bought  ,
       coalesce( sold.quantity    , 0 ) as sold    ,
       coalesce( short.quantity   , 0 ) as shorted ,
       coalesce( covered.quantity , 0 ) as covered
from      ( select distinct
                   t.Product as name
            from my_table t
          ) as product
left join ( select t.Quantity as quantity
            from my_table t
            where action = 'Buy'
          ) as bought on bought.product  = product.name 
left join ( select t.Quantity as quantity 
            from my_table t
            where action = 'Sell'
          ) sold on sold.product = product.name
left join ( select t.Quantity as quantity
            from my_table t
            where action = 'short'
          ) shorted on shorted.product = product.name
left join ( select t.Quantity as quantity
            from my_table t
            where action = 'cover'
          ) covered on covered.product = product.name
where bought.quantity > sold.quantity
   OR short.quantity  > cover.quantity
```

Another way to get to [arguably] the same result is via `group by` (but much depends on the cardinality of the data):

```sql
select t.product as product,
       sum(case t.action when 'Buy'   then t.Quantity else 0 end) as bought,
       sum(case t.action when 'Sold'  then t.Quantity else 0 end) as sold,
       sum(case t.action when 'short' then t.Quantity else 0 end) as shorted,
       sum(case t.action when 'cover' then t.Quantity else 0 end) as covered
from my_table t
group by t.product
having   sum(case t.action when 'Buy'   then t.Quantity else 0 end)
       > sum(case t.action when 'Sold'  then t.Quantity else 0 end)
    OR   sum(case t.action when 'short' then t.Quantity else 0 end)
       > sum(case t.action when 'cover' then t.Quantity else 0 end)
```

You'll note that with the `group by`, the filter moves from the `where` clause to the `having` clause. That's because the conceptual order of operations for a select statement is

1. Compute the full, cartesian join of all tables in the from clause.
2. Apply the join criteria to filter the results set.
3. Filter that by the criteria in the where clause.
4. If a `group by` clause exists, reduce the results set to to one row for each distinct combination of values in the grouping columns and compute the value of any aggregate functions.
5. Filter that summary result set by the criteria in the `having` clause.
6. Finally, if an `order by` clause exists, order the results set accordingly [without an `order by` clause, order is not guaranteed, even between 2 subsequent executions of the same exact select statement.]

Answer (score 1):

There might be way more efficient ways to do this, but you can pretty easily join them together as subqueries.

```
SELECT
    product
FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM table WHERE action = 'Buy'
    ) as bought
        JOIN
    (
        SELECT * FROM table WHERE action = 'Sell'
    ) as sold
        ON
            bought.quantity  > sold.quantity
        AND
            bought.product = sold.product
```

Comment: You should problably consider the `Product` column in the join predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Some assumptions about your table structure: each product has exactly 4 rows, one for each action, never more or less. You have no time or actionId.

This would get you a view of the data that will be more intuitive for you to work from. If you're still in the design stages, I'd consider changing this table to be more like this anyway, OR update the table to have one row per action (per sale of that product, rather than for all sales of that product).

```
SELECT 
    product, action, 
    buy.quantity AS bought, sell.quantity AS sold, 
    short.quantity AS shorts, cover.quantity AS covers
FROM
    table_name AS buy
JOIN 
    table_name AS sell ON buy.product = sell.product
JOIN 
    table_name AS short ON buy.product = short.product
JOIN 
    table_name AS cover ON buy.product = cover.product
WHERE 
    buy.action = 'Buy'
    AND sell.action = 'Sell'
    AND short.action = 'short'
    AND cover.action = 'cover';
```

If you restructure your table this way, or use this as a base query (or encode it as a VIEW), it should be intuitive for you to do the things you ask:

```
SELECT product
FROM (subquery) AS summary
WHERE bought > sold;
```

If your table is actually one row per action (as in, one row every time you sell) then you will need to do more work.